# django-keycloak | Set username as Keycloak Username (instead of Keycloak ID)

Tags: django

I am integrating Keycloak with Djnago

- https://github.com/Peter-Slump/django-keycloak/issues
- Keycloak Server

---

This is what my keycloak User Screen looks like
[image]

BUT when I log within django,

`user.email` is proper (whats present in keycloak)
`user.username` is getting set as ID from keycloak.
Is there a way to retain djnago username as keycloak username?

---

https://github.com/Peter-Slump/django-keycloak/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

In general `user.username` is actually the username in keycloak, unless the framework you use has a custom mapping to change the values (most probably with `sub` value from token in your case). If it is the case, you can add a duplicate property in token to get username as follows:

- Login to Keycloak Server with admin credentials
- Go to *Clients* section and click on the application client you are working on
- Select *Mappers* subsection in your client page
- Click on *Add Bultin*, select *username* checkbox and *Save* the settings

After you have added the token, you use it to get the username. In case the name conflicts(when mapping of *username* shares same syntax as to get *property username* from token), add a custom mapper where you can rename the property name for same username value. Custom mapper should look something like:

[image: this image]